# How do I overcome this error "Entity with key IntentTrainingPhrasKey" when restoring an agent in Dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have created a large bot and now after exporting it, I am getting this error when trying to restore it. Any tips on how to stop this error from happening?

[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euxa2.png)

Comment: Could you try to add the `en-us` locale to your new target agent and then try to restore the original agent to the new one? If you have more locales, you may need to add them to the new target agent as well. 

If this workaround works for you, you may need to use it until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I just created a new agent and imported each individual flow. It was more work but it worked in the end

Comment: According to my tests, the issue has been fixed, so you don't need to use any workaround now.